# Cpu replacement from i3 to i5

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, intel-core-i3

So I have Intel Core i5-3320M (from ThikkPad T430) and notebook PackardBell p5ws0 with Intel Core i3-2310M. Can I put i5 processor to PackardBell notebook. This site tells that socket are identicall [cpu comparision](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare.php?cmp%5B%5D=756&cmp%5B%5D=817). Will it work?

Answer (score 3):

Only if you own some really expensive tools (and even than it might be impossible). BGA stands for [Ball Grid Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array) and means (as it is often the case with Notebooks) that the CPU gets soldered to the board in order to avoid problems.

Comment: So in packard bell cpu is not replacable? like in thinkpad?

Comment: As a normal user you won't be able to replace the CPU in either device, yes.

Comment: I saw video about thinkpad where they just dissambley notebook and cpu was not soldered. I don't know if it's cou;d be done in Packard Bell's notebook.

Comment: I've had a quick look and found some videos. But in those cases (ThinkPad) the CPU was actually using [Socket G2/FCPGA988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2) the ones you linked in your comparison are BGA but actually are available as [both](https://ark.intel.com/products/52220). You would have to check your manual on what type the PackardBell is using or open it and have a look. As there are no videos for that type it could be possible that's using the BGA variation of said CPUs.

Comment: I'll do that, but main question is if Packard Bell has replacable cpu and If I put thinkpad's cpu will it be compatible with packard bell's motherboard?

Comment: As I said you will have to consult your manual on that. It should have information about replaceable parts etc. or you could open it up and have a look. You could also try to include a link to the manual or product page for that specific model in order to have someone else have a look if you're unsure.